# SonarQube does not return status of waitForQualityGate() to jenkins?

Tags: docker, jenkins, sonarqube, jenkins-pipeline, sonarqube-scan

I have used sonarQube in jenkins pipeline. I have installed all plugin related to sonarqube in jenkins. In the jenkins configure system, I configured the sonarqube server properly and jenkins global tool configuration I configured SonarQube Scanner properly.

This is jenkins pipeline code ..

```
node{
stage('git checkout process'){
  echo 'started checkout'
  git 'https://github.com/ramkumar/sampleproject'
  echo 'completed sucessfully'
}

stage('compile package'){
  def mvnTool = tool name: 'Maven', type: 'maven'
  sh "${mvnTool}/bin/mvn clean install" 
}

  stage('SonarQube analysis') {
    withSonarQubeEnv('sonarqube') {
      mvnHome = '/opt/apache-maven/bin'
      sh "${mvnHome}/mvn sonar:sonar"

    }
  }

  stage("Quality Gate"){
          timeout(time: 1, unit: 'HOURS') {
              def qg = waitForQualityGate()
              if (qg.status != 'OK') {
                  emailext body: 'Your code was failed due to sonarqube quality gate', subject: 'Jenkins Failed Report', to: 'prakashpp666666@gmail.com'
                  error "Pipeline aborted due to quality gate failure: ${qg.status}"

              }
          }
      }
```

I also configured the webhooks in sonarqube. But when I build the job the 3 stage waitForQualityGate() is not returning **ok** status back to jenkins rather it shows
**Checking status of SonarQube task 'AWrQj5In7abK9JVZ9' on server 'sonarqube'
SonarQube task 'AWrQj5In7abK9JVZ9' status is 'IN_PROGRESS'**

and it is continously loading it is not getting completed. When I check in sonarqube server it shows **Response: Server Unreachable**. I am not running sonarqube on local it is running on **docker**. What may be problem?

Answer (score 9):

**Configure SonarQube webhook for quality gate**

> Administration > Configuration > Webhooks > Create

The URL should point to your Jenkins server `http://{JENKINS_HOST}/sonarqube-webhook/`

This is solved for me. as i was unaware of this hook. Once i configured  this, everything went well.

Answer (score 4):

As suggested in the official docs [here](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/sonar/) and [here](https://docs.sonarqube.org/7.9/analysis/scan/sonarscanner-for-jenkins/), I was able to get the waitForQualityGate() working correctly by configuring a webhook to the Jenkins instance on SonarQube Server.

Add a webhook of the form your `<your-jenkins-instance>/sonarqube-webhook/` in your SonarQube server configuration, pointing to your Jenkins instance. Note the trailing slash is important.

Answer (score 3):

Try to put **sleep(60)** command before the check:

```
sleep(60)
timeout(time: 1, unit: 'MINUTES') {
    def qg = waitForQualityGate()
    print "Finished waiting"
    if (qg.status != 'OK') {
        error "Pipeline aborted due to quality gate failure: ${qg.status}"
    }
}
```

It solved same problem for me.

Comment: This can be a useful workaround, but it doesn't really solve the problem. The problem is that SonarQube is failing to trigger a Jenkins webhook when its scan finishes. By adding a delay, SonarQube can probably finish the scan before waitForQualityGate starts, so that waitForQualityGate can immediately return, instead of waiting for the webhook. If, for whatever reason, the scan isn't finished, then waitForQualityGate will still time out because the webhook isn't being fired.

Comment: It also worked for me, however, I couldn't understand why.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by creating a webhook in SonarQube.

1. In Your project / Project settings, select ***Webhooks***

[image]

2. set the url to **https://YOUR_JENKINS_URL/sonarqube-webhook/**

*p.s:* If you erroneously get FAIL from SQ, verify that the url of your SonarQube server (in Jenkins settings) **does not end in '/'**

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by [a nice article on the subject](https://thetechdarts.com/how-to-handle-inprogress-status-for-sonarqube-quality-gate/), I was able to narrow down my particular problem — which had the same *symptom* described here — to **SonarQube webhook security**:

1. Go to *Manage Jenkins* → *Configure System* → *SonarQube servers* → *Advanced...*
2. Set *Webhoot Secret* to ***SonarQube webhook secret***

So, even if you're problem isn't exactly this one, I'd *strongly* suggest reviewing both Jenkins and SonarQube settings **together** as the root cause could be something as simple...

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue. In my case it was because of an extra slash (/) in SonarQube server URL. My Jenkins -> Configure System -> SonarQube servers -> Server URL was configured as `http://sonarip:9000/`
Once I removed the trailing slash and changed it to `http://sonarip:9000`, the `waitForQualityGate` started to work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this issue was solved with 3 solutions.

1. My Jenkins -> Configure System -> SonarQube servers -> Server URL was configured as http://sonarip:9000/. Once I removed the trailing slash and changed it to http://sonarip:9000, the waitForQualityGate started to work as expected.
2. Created webhook on sonarqube, Go to Administrator -> configuration -> webhook -> http://jenkinsserverip/sonarqube-webhook/
3. Create a secret for the webhook and configure in jenkins